# Stored Procedure to take date range from one table and use the results in WHERE clause in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure that will take `@start_dt` and `@end_dt` parameters from a view and use them as parameters in a `WHERE` clause on another table.

I am trying to get the total number of HEATS between `@start_dt` and `@end_dt`. Then I need to insert the result of this `SELECT` statement into a table.

How do I declare `@start_dt` and `@end_dt` in the procedure? How do I use a cursor that will navigate through each pair of `@start_dt` and `@end_dt` and do the COUNT on heats?

This query is half the way done:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_EAF_HEAT_COUNT
AS
    SELECT 
        @START_DT as START_DT, 
        @END_DT as END_DT, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT HEAT_ID) AS NUM_HEATS
    FROM 
        [SSABDB].[L2].[EAF_HEAT] 
    WHERE 
        PROCESS_UNIT = 'EAFA'
        AND START_DT > @START_DT 
        AND END_DT < @END_DT

    INSERT INTO DASH.EAFA_HEAT_COUNT (START_DT, END_DT, FURNACE, NUM_HEATS) 
    VALUES (@START_DT, @END_DT, 'A', NUM_HEATS)
END
```

[image]

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO



CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spEAFA_HEAT_COUNT]
 
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE 
       @START_DT datetime
       ,@END_DT datetime
       ,@CNT_HEATS INT


DECLARE tblCursor CURSOR FOR   
       SELECT 
               START_DT , END_DT
       FROM 
              dbo.EAFA_T
      
       ORDER BY 
              END_DT
  
OPEN tblCursor  
  
FETCH NEXT FROM tblCursor   
INTO @START_DT, @END_DT 
  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
select @CNT_HEATS = Count(distinct HEAT_ID)
  FROM [DATABASENAME].[SCHEMANAME].[TABLENAME] where PROCESS_UNIT = 'EAFA'
AND  START_DT > @START_DT and END_DT < @END_DT
 
INSERT INTO Dashboard.EAFA_HEAT_COUNT (START_DT, END_DT, FURNACE, NUM_HEATS) VALUES (@START_DT, @END_DT, 'A', @CNT_HEATS)
 
    FETCH NEXT FROM tblCursor   
    INTO @START_DT, @END_DT 
END  


CLOSE tblCursor;  
DEALLOCATE tblCursor;  


END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, it should be a direct insert without any need for a cursor

Eg:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_EAF_HEAT_COUNT(@START_DT  date, @END_DT date)    
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT 
     INTO DASH.EAFA_HEAT_COUNT 
          (START_DT
          , END_DT
          , FURNACE
          , NUM_HEATS
          ) 
  SELECT MAX(b.START_DT)
       , MAX(b.END_DT)
       , COUNT(distinct HEAT_ID) as NUM_HEATS
    FROM [SSABDB].[L2].[EAF_HEAT] a
    JOIN dbo.EAFA_T b
      ON a.START_DT > b.START_DT 
     AND a.END_DT < b.END_DT            
   WHERE a.PROCESS_UNIT = 'EAFA'
GROUP BY concat(convert(varchar(12),b.START_DT,101),'_',convert(varchar(12),b.END_DT,101))

END
```

Updating based on the comment, again!

Comment: in your select query, you have to use variables  START_DT,  END_DT, so that we get single row as INSERT

Comment: `MAX(@START_DT)` , `MAX(@END_DT)` You don't need the `MAX()` function here

Comment: you are right, habits die hard from using Oracle

Comment: START_DT and END_DT are columns in a VIEW. Say V_TIMERANGE. How do I take input from this view for @START_DT and @ENT_DT?

Comment: 1. is start_dt and end_dt going to be be unique in the view  2. are there no overlaps between dates in V_TIMERANGE

Answer (score 0):

There is one more approach.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_EAF_HEAT_COUNT(@START_DT  DATETIME, @END_DT DATETIME)
  
AS
BEGIN

--Finding Count 
DECLARE @CNT_HEADID = (SELECT 
  SELECT Count(distinct HEAT_ID) as NUM_HEATS
  FROM [SSABDB].[L2].[EAF_HEAT] where PROCESS_UNIT = 'EAFA'
AND  START_DT > @START_DT and END_DT < @END_DT)
   
-- Inserting the Count
   INSERT INTO DASH.EAFA_HEAT_COUNT (START_DT, END_DT, FURNACE, NUM_HEATS) VALUES (@START_DT, @END_DT, 'A', @CNT_HEADID)
END
```

Comment: START_DT and END_DT are columns in a VIEW. Say V_TIMERANGE. How do I take input from this view for @START_DT and @ENT_DT?

Comment: so, you want for every combination of START_DT and END_DT, find the COUNT ? In that case, we have to apply GROUP BY

Comment: Found the answer. Had help from my DBA. Thank you.

Comment: @Abhinavneni, please add your answer and mark your answer as the answer, so it will be helpful for others in future